# Which 6D pose estimation package works best and will be supported?

Tags: ros, pose

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have seen several different solutions to 6D pose estimation in ROS/opencv:

checkerboard_detector

checkerboard_detector2

checkerboard_pose_estimation

datamatrix

fiducial

datamatrix seems less accurate than the checkerboard approach, but the checkerboard packages seem to no longer be supported.  The fiducial package seems new (used in the tod_training contest), but there is no documentation.

Is willow/openCV settling on the fiducial package?  I'd like to choose the one that works best right now and also won't disappear any time soon...
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9681/which-6d-pose-estimation-package-works-best-and-will-be-supported?/) by [sdavies](https://answers.ros.org/users/406/sdavies/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2011-04-08

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have used fiducial markers from tod_training for collecting training data and pose estimation and it worked fine so far (using object_recognition in SVN 50321).

---

Originally posted by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) with karma: 960 on 2011-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had no success with "checkerboard_detection" in February but was assured by the author, they would update the software "after some time". Haven't tried since.

checkerboard_detector2 works for me.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-04-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can check out [ar_pose](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ar_pose), as well as [ar_pose_ekf](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ar_pose_ekf), for a 6D pose estimation using single or multiple AR markers.

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2011-04-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2